# Sort list<keyValuePair<string,string>>

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing it in `C#` `.net2.0`
I am having a list which contains two strings and i want to sort it.
list is like `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

I have to sort it according to the first `string`, which is:

- ACC
- ABLA
- SUD
- FLO
- IHNJ

I tried to use `Sort()`, but it gives me the exception: *"Invalid operation exception","Failed to compare two elements in array"*.

Can you suggest me anyway in which I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are stuck with .NET 2.0, you will have to create a class that implements `IComparer<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` and pass an instance of it to the `Sort` method:

```
public class KvpKeyComparer<TKey, TValue> : IComparer<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
    where TKey : IComparable
{
    public int Compare(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> x,
                       KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        if(x.Key == null)
        {
            if(y.Key == null)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }

        if(y.Key == null)
            return 1;

        return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
    }
}

list.Sort(new KvpKeyComparer<string, string>());
```

If you would use a newer version of the .NET framework, you could use LINQ:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: can u tell me how to make a class IComparer or any tutorial where i can easily find how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a SortedDictionary instead?

Here's the MSDN article on it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the `Comparison<T>` generic delegate. Then you avoid the need to define a class just to implement `IComparer<T>` but rather just need to ensure that you define your method to match the delegate signature.

```
private int CompareByKey(KeyValuePair<string, string>, KeyValuePair<string, string> y)
{
    if (x.Key == null & y.Key == null) return 0;
    if (x.Key == null) return -1;
    if (y.Key == null) return 1;

    return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
}

list.Sort(CompareByKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Vilnius", "Algirdas"));
pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Trakai", "Kestutis"));

pairs.Sort(delegate (KeyValuePair<String, String> x, KeyValuePair<String, String> y) { return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key); });
foreach (var pair in pairs)
     Console.WriteLine(pair);
Console.ReadKey();
```